# "Out Of Memory Error" while using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I have been getting too many **out of memory errors while using recyclerview and loading images from urls**. The memory profiler shows that memory allocations keeps on increasing even if we revisit the same fragments again.

I have also read several SO questions regarding this and haven't found a solution yet. I have tried the following so far

1. Using smaller contexts in Glide.with() eg Fragments, Individual
   Views
2. Skipmemorycache(true)

None of the above have solved my problem yet

Comment: Have you tried to manually clear the ImageView? Look into your memory monitor carefully and try to see exactly where and when your memory is leaking.

Comment: @viz The imageviews are in recyclerview items.